# SQL Server Auditing and Website

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to use SQL Server Auditing when the primary database interaction is from a website without impersonation?

All database actions come from a web application whose connection string uses a single logon / password.  In the website, user authentication / creation comes from the membership provider, but is not passed through to the SQL Server.  I would like to audit which website user performed which action on the SQL Server using the built-in audit mechanism.

Comment: You won't likely be able to use any of the built-in audit features and discern which user did what, since everything is running under one login/user account. There may still be options though, depending on how your web app accesses the database. If you're using stored procedures for CRUD, for example, you could have those calls logged and pass a User ID from your membership provider in to each one as a parameter.

Comment: How would the built in audit mechanism know about the users in your application when they aren't even connecting to the database?  You will have to implement some auditing features yourself to achieve this.

Comment: I suspected that, but I guess I was hoping for a obscure workaround.  Thanks for the input.